# NestJS: Unable to connect to MongoDB using MongooseModule.forRootAsync

Tags: nestjs, nestjs-mongoose

I am trying to connect to local mongoDB in the `AppModule` by doing the following but it won't connect:

```
imports: [
    MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => {
        return {
          uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/client',
          useNewUrlParser: true,
          useCreateIndex: true,
        };
      },
    }),
  ],
```

Error from NestJS:
`[MongooseModule] Unable to connect to the database. Retrying (1)...`

The MongoDB is running fine. I can connect to it through MongoDB Compass with the same uri.

What is done wrong causing the connection not being established?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**useNewUrlParser** , **useUnifiedTopology** , **useFindAndModify** , and **useCreateIndex** are no longer supported options,İf you remove that option everything will works.From the Mongoose [6.0 docs](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migrating_to_6.html#no-more-deprecation-warning-options):

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => ({
        uri: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/client',
      }),
    }),
```

Comment: Removing the options works like a charm! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**This works with async and logging options**

```
MongooseModule.forRootAsync({
      useFactory: async () => {
        const connection = await ConnectToMongodb.getConnectionString();
        return {
          connectionFactory: (connection) => {
            if (connection.readyState === 1) {
              console.log('Database Connected successfully');
            }
            connection.on('disconnected', () => {
              console.log('Database disconnected');
            });
            connection.on('error', (error) => {
              console.log('Database connection failed! for error: ', error);
            });

            return connection;
          },
          uri: connection,
        };
      },
    })
```